# How to get value of Selected radio button from table and then count selected radio button using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to get value selected radio button using jQuery

[image]

Comment: is that helps `$("input[type='radio'][name='yourRadioName']:checked").val();` ?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from my example, i select all radio box then sum it and put result into `<p>`

```js
let total = 0;
$('table input:radio:checked').each(function() {
  total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val());
});
$("p").html(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='radio' value='1' checked>1</td>
    <td><input type='radio' value='2'>2</td>
    <td><input type='radio' value='3' checked>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
total:
<p></p>
```

[You might not need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/):

```js
let total = 0;
let radios = document.querySelectorAll('table input[type="radio"]:checked');
radios.forEach((radio)=>{
  total += isNaN(parseInt(radio.value)) ? 0 : parseInt(radio.value);
});
document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = total;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='radio' value='1' checked>1</td>
    <td><input type='radio' value='2'>2</td>
    <td><input type='radio' value='3' checked>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
total:
<p></p>
```